# How to create a URL with the value from dropdown in jquery/ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to create a url for `ajax` call like below:

`myurl.php?ym=201609`

`ym` value should be get from a dropdown change. And then that value need to be pass for above url.

This is how I tried it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#salStatePeriod").change(function() {
    window.period = $(this).val(); 

    alert(window.period);
  }); 

  var table = $(".salary_statement").dataTable({
     "ajax": {
         "url":'./process_datatable.php?ym='+window.period,
         "type":"POST",
         "extend":function( response ) {
             // $(this).json = response; 
             $("#total").html(this.data.total);
          }
      }

  });  
});
```

But it doesn't work for me. Its output like this:
`/process_datatable.php?ym=undefined`

Can anybody tell me, how I figure this out?

Comment: You need to put the actual ajax request in a function that can be called on the `change` event for the dropdown control. You could also put the ajax code inside the `change` method after you have assigned the `window.period` value.

Comment: @Cyclone, can you show me an example?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why is this question tagged with PHP, but does not show any PHP code? Is this really related to PHP?

Answer (score 2):

try to get the value directly in your data table ajax call.

```
$("#salStatePeriod").change(function() {
        $(".salary_statement").dataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url":'./process_datatable.php?ym='+this.val(),
                "type":"POST",
                "extend":function( response ) {
                    // $(this).json = response; 
                    $("#total").html(this.data.total);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: see the change i just made, just when drop down list change call the your data table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the actual ajax request in a function that can be called on the change event for the dropdown control:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function sendNotification (index) {
     $(".salary_statement").dataTable({
         ajax: {
         url: './process_datatable.php?ym=' + index,
         type: "POST",
         extend :function (response) {
            // $(this).json = response; 
            $("#total").html(this.data.total);
         }
       }
    });
  }

  $("#salStatePeriod").change(function () {
    sendNotification($(this).val());
  });  
});
```

You could also put the ajax code inside the change method after you have assigned the window.period value:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#salStatePeriod").change(function () {
    $(".salary_statement").dataTable({
       ajax: {
         url: './process_datatable.php?ym=' + $(this).val(),
         type: "POST",
         extend: function (response) {
            // $(this).json = response; 
            $("#total").html(this.data.total);
         }
       }
    });
  });  
});
```